# Adding border to CSS triangle

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have a triangle

```
<div class="triangle-left"></div>


.triangle-left {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 22px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 22px solid transparent;
    border-right: 22px solid white;
}
```

How do I draw the outline of a CSS triangle, considering `border` itself is used to make the triangle? External divs?

Comment: Make another triangle that's red and one pixel wider and then put the white triangle over it and you have a white triangle with a red border.

Comment: Use the triangle technique described in [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24808936/2930477).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

One way to do it is the create an inner triangle which is smaller.

```css
.triangle-left {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 23px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 23px solid transparent;
    border-right: 23px solid red;
}

.inner-triangle {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: 2px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-left">
    <div class="inner-triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: how would you do this if the triangle was in an `li:after` element?

Answer (score 33):

This is how I would do it.

```css
.triangle-left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 22px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 22px solid transparent;
  border-right: 22px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.triangle-left:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 21px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 21px solid transparent;
  border-right: 21px solid #dddddd;
  position: absolute;
  top: -21px;
  left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-left"></div>
```

Here it is on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joncampbell/3rhh70u2/).