# CSS how to draw arrow on vertical line

Tags: css

How to add an arrow on the CSS vertical line by using just pure CSS?

My vertical line is just using the CSS border-right only, then I want to add a two-lines arrow on this line to make it like an arrow, like this:

[image]

```
<div  class="ve-line"></div>

.ve-line{
border-right: 1px solid rgb(232, 232, 232);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create [CSS triangle by using border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work) than add [another one larger triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29001636/adding-border-to-css-triangle) to create *border like* style and position it absolutly with `right: -1px` to place it on the line.

```css
.ve-line{
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(232, 232, 232);
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  right: -1px;
  top: 100px;
}

.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.triangle:before {
  border-top: 22px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 22px solid transparent;
  border-right: 22px solid rgb(232, 232, 232);
}

.triangle:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 2px;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div  class="ve-line">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```